# Welcome banner on main page obscures top panel

Tags: bug, status-deferred

When I went to the main page this morning, the "Welcome to our site" banner (or whatever it says) obscured the top panel containing the "log in" button.

This was on Firefox 3.6 (technically speaking, Namoroka) on Linux.

Comment: It works for me (FF 3.6.8, Ubuntu 10.04). Both with Javascript enabled and disabled.

Comment: Confirmed (FF 3.6.8, Win7). I submitted it to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design -- if the greeting is 2 lines wide (depends on length of message being presented), it has to be larger.

Just click the [x] to close it and proceed.

Comment: Can't it simply shove the rest of the stuff down a bit?  If it's only one's second time here then one might have forgotten where the 'log in' link is - it's small enough as it is that hiding it behind a banner makes it a bit unwelcoming.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: I think one is *supposed* to close the banner before proceeding; that's why it's so large and distracting and has a prominent [x] close button. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd noticed that too: I wonder if it is a bug of a 'feature'!

Comment: Congratulations on the 2000 rep, by the way!

Comment: I picked the right questions to answer :-)

Comment: “all of them”? ;-)